# Hiberate : HQL Case Insensitive search

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

My requirement is to do a search in database based on a string.

That particular string might be stored in uppercase, in database.

So, I will have to do a case-insensitive search through HQL

My current HQL is

```
String query = "from OrganizationContent where orgUrl=:url";
        Map<String,Object> parameterMap = new HashMap<String,Object>();
        parameterMap.put("url", organizationUrlInput.toLowerCase());
```

Only ".toLowerCase" I can do from java end. Now I need hibernate to fetch the data by doing a case-insensitive search.

Appreciate your help on this friends

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#queryhql-expressions):

> Expressions used in the where clause include the following:
>
> [...]
>
> Any function or operator defined by EJB-QL 3.0: substring(), trim(),
>   lower(), upper(), length(), locate(), abs(), sqrt(), bit_length(),
>   mod()

```
from OrganizationContent where lower(orgUrl) = :url
```